# jQuery.Deferred exception: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: php, jquery, stripe-payments

I am getting this error suddenly. It was all working fine, but suddenly it begin to come up and due to that my Stripe Payment Form is not appearing at all.

Error

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0  at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Attaching images also from console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqwc0.png)

And

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1eUd.png)

Comment: That error means it's not JSON, most likely has extra HTML.   Should be obvious if you look at the unprocessed result.

Comment: Did you try a [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5DUnexpected+token+%3C+in+JSON+at+position+0+) ?

Comment: Search? Sorry couldn't get you. But all i tried, my Stripe payment form isn't getting displayed yet.

Comment: At the top of the SO page is a search box - copy your error there or click the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't a JSON or HTML Error.
This was an issue with Stripe communication. I mean, TLS version 1.2 needed to communicate with stripe.
Reinstalled the Stripe latest libraries and the issue was fixed

Comment: The error regarding the TLS issue would have been returned as HTML. The problem was 100% due to the HTML format of the response, when jQuery was told by your code to expect JSON.